# Получить нормальное название устройства захвата звука

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Как и где можно получить нормальное название устройства захвата звука а не то что отдает `QString QAudioDeviceInfo::deviceName()`.

Т.к. то что он отдает выглядит следующим образом: `alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo`, думаю тут понятны причины почему нужно нормальное название устройства, или `HumanReadable`, пользователь думаю не сможет определиться с устройством если ему отдать такие названия устройств.

UPD: При попытке получить имена устройств на Windows, список устройств содержит нормальные имена:

> "Микрофон (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
>
> "Стерео микшер (Realtek High Definition Audio)"

Comment: `lspci` и `lshw` можно глянуть кодовую этих проектов.

Comment: Вы путаете название устройства с именами Source и Sink. ALSA умеет отдавать и их, вам надо посмотреть в код *alsamixer*, там должно быть более или менее понятно — она чисто консольная.